# mysql/mariadb single database replication with read-write-split only for this single database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

In my setup there are two debian servers. The first one is the old production server and the second is the new one. On the first (old) one runs a mysql v5.5 db-server and an old application which lags support. It cannot be ported easily to the new server. The new server runs mariadb v10.1 and all the other applications were ported from the old server to this new one. These applications have to work also with the data of the application that cannot be ported.
The ported application can only access local databases. So there is no easy way of changing the connection for these apps to the old db server.

My idea:
I want to replicate (master->slave) the data of the **one** database (used by the old application that is not portable) of the mysql v5.5 db server to the maraidb v10.1 db-server.
No problem so far.

But the applications on the new server not only read the data of the old application, they can also modify them. And they also have there own databases that only exists on the new server. This is a problem as far as I know and can lead to the break of the replication in some situations if the applications would try to write at the replicated database on the slave.
My next thought to solve this was that I can make use of a sql dispatcher proxy and found some interesting ones (mariadb maxscale, haproxy, proxySQL) but as far as I understood they can split read and write operations but I couldn't find a way to route write operations for different databases to different servers.

Can Anybody give me a hint to solve this problem?

Setting:

Server 1 - Mysql v5.5 - database_1

Server 2 - Mariadb v10.1 - database_1, database_2, database_3

An application on server 1 is writing and reading data from database_1 on server 1.
Other applications on server 2 are reading and writing data to database_1 on server 2.

So the data of database_1 have to be replicated from server 1 to server 2 and could be changed there.

A master-master replication instead of master-slave could work, but in reason of auto_increment fields that could break the replication and in reason of the fact that the changed data from server 2 doesn't have to exist on server 1, I think this is not the way to go. (I'm aware that I could set the auto_increment interval to two to avoid this problem, but it's an already running production system, so changes like this are not so easy).

At the moment we're doing backups by hand and copy them over but that's way to slow and I'm sure there is a better way ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use write to a replication slave (server 2) for databases like database_2 and database_3 that will never appear in the replication scream.

If you started updating database_1 you probably would end up in trouble.

You are replicating between two database server of over a major version difference so there is the possibility that a deprecated SQL statement gets replicated to a server that has it removed and the replication will stop. Keep an eye out for this in the weeks after deployment. binlog_format=ROW may mitigate some of the SQL that could got incorrectly.

Comment: Ok. That's what I thought. But there is no common "hack" like: "replicate the db and use trigger to fill another database with the same data. Write only to the db, that is updated with the triggers and never touch / write to the replicated db." And: There is no way of using a read-write-split for only one database on one server but keep the other databases of the same server uneffected? If this would be possible there would be no problem. BUt I couldn't find any information if this is possible.

Comment: There are [replication filters](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/replication-filters/) which do a lot of these. Read the documentation carefully on these however.